# Arithmetic sum proof problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to work a problem which asks me to find an explicit summation formula for $$\sum_{k=1}^n k$$ but I am confused about the result I got which seems to work but then doesn't...

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  1+2+3+\dots+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+(n)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  ([1+(n-1)]+[2+(n-2)]+[3+(n-3)]+\dots) + (n)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  [[n]+[n]+[n]+\dots]+(n)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  n*\frac{(n-1)}{2} +(n)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  \frac{n(n-1)}{2} +(\frac{2n}{2})$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Then when I try to apply it to some arbitrary even number, say n=6...I become kind of confused

$\sum_{k=1}^6 k= 1 + 2 + 3 +4 + 5 +6$

$[[1+(6-1)]+[2+(6-2)]+ 3??] + (6)$

But for an arbitrary odd number, say n=5, it seems to work as intended

$\sum_{k=1}^5 k= 1 + 2 + 3 +4 + 5 $

$[[1+(5-1)]+[2+(5-2)]] + (5)$

Is my "proof" wrong? 
There is something which I do not grasp correctly but I can't seem to put my finger on exactly what it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof is very... misleading on some steps. What's inside the $\dots$? How did you pull a division by $2$ from the $[[n]+[n]+[n]+\dots]+(n)$ step?

Comment: Good questions. I'm still trying to answer them myself. I must have incorrectly assumed a few things such as the number of remaining [n] being even. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof only
works for odd numbers,
because,
when you remove $n$ there 
are an even number left
which you then pair up.

For even numbers,
don't remove anything
and just pair them up
in pairs that add up to
$n+1$ like this:

$\begin{array}\\
1+2+...+(n-1)+n
&=(1+n)+(2+(n-1))+...((n/2)+(n/2+1))\\
&=(n+1)+(n+1)+...(n+1)\ (n/2 \text{ times})\\
&=(n+1)(n/2)\\
\end{array}
$

Another way
(made famous by Gauss)
that works for all $n$
is to add the sum twice
with the second
in reverse order:

$\begin{array}\\
2(1+2+...+(n-1)+n)
&=(1+2+...+(n-1)+n)+(n+(n-1)+...+2+1)\\
&=(1+n)+(2+(n-1))...+((n-1)+2)+(n+1))\\
&=(1+n)+(1+n)...+(1+n)\ (n \text{ times})\\
&=(n+1)n\\
\text{so}\\
(1+2+...+(n-1)+n)
&=\dfrac{(n+1)n}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

For even $n$ (say $6$),

$$1+2+3+4+5+6=(1+6)+(2+5)+(3+4)=(1+n)\frac n2.$$

For odd $n$ (say $7$),

$$1+2+3+4+5+6+7=(1+7)+(2+6)+(3+5)+4=(1+n)\frac{n-1}2+\frac{n+1}2.$$

In both cases,

$$\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$

Answer (score 2):

***HINT***

(Basically you are trying to imitate the fabled proof Gauss came up with as a child.)

You can make $\Large\frac n2$ pairs that all sum to $n+1$ if $n$ is even but if $n$ is odd you van make at most $\Large\frac{n-1}{2}$ such pairs to which you must still add the final $n$ to correctly represent your sum.

You should try to make a distinction from the second step to the third depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Actually, Gauss' proof works for all $n$. See my answer.

Comment: @martycohen Of course it does, I did not mean to imply otherwise, I was mainly comparing the idea of pairing equal sums as similar but I guess that "replicate" I put is not the right wording. I will replace it with "imitate" to dispel any confusion. Anyway, +1 for a much more concise answer and thank you for the heads up.