# Understanding how $\sum_{k=1}^n(3k+1)$ has been simplified

Tags: analysis, summation

I want to understand how $\sum_{k=1}^n(3k+1)$ has been simplified here:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(3k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n 1+3\sum_{k=1}^nk=n+3 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2} (2n+3n^2 + 3n) = \frac{1}{2}n (3n+5)$$

I understand the first step and the last step.

What I dont understand is how you get from

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 1+3\sum_{k=1}^nk$$

to

$$n+3 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: The latter summation is a well-known identity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are simpling using that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 1=\overbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}^{n\text{ copies}}=n$$

and the well known result

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Refer to the related:

- [Arithmetic sum proof problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474162/505767)

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for the editing!

Comment: I was just about to make my own answer when yours popped up, so I had it in my head to use the overbrace :)

Comment: @alex.jordan You know, I was also adding that in oder to make things more clear! Thanks again, really appreciative contribution.